# How to make firefox proxy authentication fail silently?

Tags: firefox, proxy

At work, certain protocols are blocked, and websites that I visit try to access these protocols with Javascript. These sites work fine when these requests fail (except for whatever it's trying to do with the requests), but I have to click cancel on a multitude of proxy authentication dialogs.

What I want to do is just have firefox silently ignore this, so I can use the website without having to click cancel 8 times on every action I make (this includes all the stack overflow style sites which is trying to make requests with the ws: protocol).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem; some sites cause multiple proxy authentication requests to be issued.

If your firm uses a proxy, just add the URL you want to block on the "no proxy list" of Firefox to avoid that.  Start by adding "sockets.ny.stackexchange.com" to the "no proxy list".

The URL would try to access without using proxy, fail, and it's done.

Quick and dirty but works :)

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can disable this dialog in Firefox, at least not without undesirable side-efects.
But there are utilities that will get rid of such nag-windows as soon as they appear, in effect clicking the Cancel button for you.

Here are some such free utilities (that I have never used) :

[ClickOff](http://www.johanneshuebner.com/en/clickoff.shtml)
[Window Clicker](http://www.murgee.com/window-clicker/)
[NagBlast](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Internet/Popup-Ad-Spyware-Blockers/NagBlast.shtml)

If for some reason none of them is right for you, you can always roll your own by using
a macro recording tool such as [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/).

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is already resolved and a bit old, but I ran into the same problem, and I have found a solution that is a bit more convenient than adding every restricted site to the no proxy list:

Get [Adblock Plus](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/adblock-plus/) if you haven't already, and create a custom filter with the hostname specified in the authentication popup, in the following format:

```
||subdomain.domain.com^
```

This will effectively mute authentication requests. Even if the hostname is the proxy address itself, it shouldn't cause any problem. The only drawback is if access to that address is required for some of your online duties, then it's obviously not a good idea to block it.